# Firebase RecyclerView expandable view not working (Do not wish to use any 3rd Party Library)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have used a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in my application for displaying a series of events. When i select an event form the recycler view it must expand the recycler view item and show me the details and other items of that event such as dates, description and others. I used a concept from **Google I/O 2016** but could't land anywhere as my event is not showing only. I want only a specific set of items to be displayed when expanded.

**EventView.java**

```
public class EventView extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int mExpandedPosition = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_view);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ApprovedEvents");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.request_EventList);

        //Avoid unnecessary layout passes by setting setHasFixedSize to true
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Select the type of layout manager you would use for your recyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final String event_cat  = getIntent().getStringExtra("Category");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, RequestViewHolder>(
                Event.class,
                R.layout.events_list_row,
                RequestViewHolder.class,
                databaseReference.orderByChild("category").equalTo(event_cat)
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(RequestViewHolder viewHolder, Event model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setCategory(model.getCategory());
                viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
                viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setImageUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageUrl());

                viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(EventView.this, "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RequestViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
                super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);

                final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;


                viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
                viewHolder.mView.setActivated(isExpanded);
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class RequestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        ImageView imageButton;

        public RequestViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            imageButton = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_image);
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView a_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_title);
            a_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView a_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_desc);
            a_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            TextView a_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_location);
            a_desc.setText(location);
        }

        public void setCategory(String category) {
            TextView a_category = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_category);
            a_category.setText(category);
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            TextView a_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_price);
            a_price.setText(price);
        }

        public void setImageUrl(Context ctx, String imageUrl) {
            ImageView a_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.request_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageUrl).into(a_image);
        }
    }
}
```

**events_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/request_category"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Category will come here"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/request_location"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Location will come here"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/request_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:text="Title will come here "
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/request_desc"
            android:text="Desc will come here "
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:id="@+id/request_image"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price will come here"
            android:id="@+id/request_price"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_event_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.college20.EventView">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/request_EventList"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```